# Как сделать редирект в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Такая проблема
При переходе на сайт
https:/site.ru/* - показывает главную страницу а не 404.
До этого были множественные слэши и знак вопроса https://site.ru/?
Решил проблему так.

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
# Проверяем, повторяется ли слеш (//) более двух раз.
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
# Исключаем все лишние слеши.

# Убираем знак вопроса в конце URL (/?)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^\s]+\s+[^?]*?\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Но странно, при входе https:/site.ru/* , по идее должен отдавать 404.

Как правильно сделать перенаправление?

Comment: Можно сделать проверку: Если это не файл и не директория, то перенаправляем на главное зеркало.
Или же нужно вывести 404 ошибку?

Comment: Да нет ,хотел сделать чтоб с https:/site.ru/* переходило на главное зеркало. Но выходит циклический редирект.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [L,R=301]
```

Если это не файл и не директория, то перенаправляем на главное зеркало